# Two entities having one to many relationship with another entity

Tags: sql, hibernate, design-patterns

I have three enttites A,B and C. The relation is as follows:

```
A is One To many with C
B is One to many with C
```

If I have only one of the above, I use to keep a "id" of A/B in C as a foreign key. But in this case I am not getting how to do it.

An entry in C either belongs to A or B not both.

I am using Hibernate as ORM, and MySQL as database. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, could you please share the best design?

Answer (score 0):

I Faced the same problem, and I've found the only solution is to use an abstract class, because we cannot make a foreign key that dynamic, here is the example I used:

```
public abstract class AbstractC{
private int id;
}

@Entity...
public class CbelongsToA extends AbstractC{
@ManyToOne...
private A a;
}

@Entity...
public class CbelongsToB extends AbstractC{
@ManyToOne...
private B b;
}

public class A{
@OneToMany
private List<CbelongsToA> cbelongToA;
}

public class B{
@OneToMany
private List<CbelongsToB> cbelongToB;
}
```

Comment: I think I am missing something, so you created two tables for C?

Comment: yes you will have to use 2 entities, one belongs to A and the other Belongs to B

Comment: Is this right? having two entities that are exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

Sorrry I'm not so familiar with MySQL, but it may be that general decision will work in your case. In some other DBMS's I would solve this problem by creating:

1. Two NULL-able FK's in table C (FK's to table A and B respectively)
2. Table constraint checking that both FK's are not nulled or filled at
   the same time.

Something like that (pseudo-sql, just for illustration):

```
CREATE TABLE C (
C_DATA varchar(255),
A_ID int NULL,
B_ID int NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES A(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (B_ID) REFERENCES B(ID),
CONSTRAINT chk_c_fks CHECK (A_ID IS NOT NULL XOR B_ID IS NOT NULL))
```